# adb устанавливается с AndroidStudio или его надо ставить отдельно?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, adb

У меня Windows c установленной AndroidStudio.

Ввожу команду adb devices , в консоли пишет, что нет такой команды.

Где в AndroidStudio подключение  adb или оно отдельно ставится?

Answer (score 5):

В AndroidStudio открываете File -> Project Structure, там смотрите путь до Android SDK, adb находится в папке platform-tools внутри SDK. Если хотите запускать adb не указывая к ней путь из любой папки добавьте путь до неё в переменную среды PATH.

Comment: В *SDK Manager* убедитесь, что у вас установлен пакет `platform-tools`